# Do tab ID and root URL ever change from within the content script for a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

From a standpoint of the *content script* injected into a web page by my Google Chrome extension, do tab ID and root URL of the web page ever change?

(By *root URL* I assume the URL of the top window in the possible IFRAMEs hierarchy.)

Or, in other words, is it safe to retrieve tab ID and root URL when the *content script* starts running and cache it in the global variable for a later use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the URL can change.

While any navigation will unload the script, [history manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) like `history.pushState()` will not; you will have a brand new, <del>arbitrary</del> same-origin URL and the old copy of the content script. What's worse, there is no event to easily intercept that.

As for `tabId`, this *should* be constant, but if the page navigates away, the `tabId` will not change but the content script will.

Comment: Thanks. So is there a way to get the top window URL. The `document.url` will return it for the iframe only.

Comment: OK, scratch that. Got the top window URL by using `window.top.document.URL` (from the content script.) It's the same for all IFRAMEs.